# Laravel Repositories and Eloquent Models

Tags: php, laravel, model, repository, eloquent

After reading a few tutorials and mostly watching videos on `Laracasts`, I was considering adding an abstraction layer in my website using `Repositories` which would be injected in my `Controllers` through an interface. The `Repositories` are there to abstract how the `Model` is retrieved and hide some business logic. Using the `Bind` method available in `Laravel`, this seemed super easy and convenient.

This sounds super interesting to add `unit tests` to a project, but I fail to understand how the `Model` should be handled.

For example, let's say we're trying to hide the good old `User` model behind a repository, by creating:

```
interface UserRepositoryInterface {
    public function getAll();
    // ...
}
```

Then, to support the standard `User` model provided by Laravel, defined as:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    // ...
}
```

We create an `Eloquent` implementation of the `UserRepositoryInterface`:

```
class EloquentUserRepository extends UserRepositoryInterface {
    public function getAll() {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

The part that I don't understand is that now, the `Repository` doesn't return a "generic" `Model`, it returns an `Eloquent` model!  It doesn't make sense to me that other `Repositories` should return the same type of `Model`, and if it's not the case, what's the point of having `Repositories` if there is no correlation at all between the `Models` returned?

**What then is the proper usage of the `Repository` pattern within `Laravel`?**

Comment: I would normally use `return User::all()->toArray();` in `EloquentUserRepository::getAll();` when I strictly want repository to return non-implementation-specific data. But I violate that rule myself sometimes because returning Eloquent models is so convenient. :p I wish Eloquent has a `toObject()` method!

Comment: The truth is, if you don't need that extra layer, then don't. Implement it when it's necessary. And when you do, that's correct, returning `Eloquent` is rather not the way to go. Instead you can return an `array` or implement what @Unnawut is talking about, e.g. like Andreas here: https://github.com/anlutro/laravel-4-core/blob/master/src/Eloquent/Collection.php#L30-L48

Comment: [This may give you some idea](http://heera.it/laravel-repository-pattern).

Comment: @Unnawut return (object) $this->toArray();

Answer (score 2):

`Repositories` in `Laravel` help keep controllers thin and dumb.

`Controllers` get to handle any route or data parsing before handing to the repository, and returning data in proper formats.

`Repositories` get to handle the models.

If you have both of these functions are in the same controller method, you have trouble determining if the issue is in the parsing of the data from the input, or the requesting of data from the model.

This separation allows use to make sure the `controller` is handing appropriate data to the `repository`.  That the `repository` is performing the appropriate validations and accessing the `model` in the correct manner, and that all of these are returning data of the correct type.

The repositories returned `model` can be tested for type using `instanceof`:

```
public function testAllReturnsCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->machineRepository->all();
    $this->assertTrue($collection instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection);
}

public function testFindReturnsMachine()
{
    $model = $this->machineRepository->find($this->machineId);
    $this->assertTrue($model instanceof Machine);
}
```

This type of testing can also be done with `Mocking`, but when working with models I prefer to use a test database.

Comment: What about moving repository methods to the model in the case where the queries does not involve multiple different models?